# Wearing neoprene suit in airplane?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security, security, clothing

Do airlines generally prohibit wearing a neoprene suit underneath one's regular clothes?

It could be useful in the event of a plane crash in the middle of the ocean, as a neoprene suit could keep one warm in cold water.

Comment: (apart from looking silly) You'd probably suffer from Hyperthermia in the plane.

Comment: This sounds like it would be exceedingly uncomfortable if you're planning to wear it the entire flight. How many instances of a plane crash in the middle of the ocean where there were survivors who weren't able to get to a life raft have there even been? And the water in the middle of the ocean is damn cold; a wetsuit won't do you much good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, no.  There is no prohibition on wearing neoprene.

However, there is no conceivable benefit to wearing neoprene as a protective measure in case of ditching.  A neoprene suit would have such a narrow surviveability window that you'd be much more likely to injure yourself donning and removing it.

Basically, it would only help after a successful controlled ditch in temperate climates where rescue is rescue is between 1-4 hours away and all rafts have failed.

Comment: The bigger reason it's useless in practice is that ditching in water is extremely rare, because it's also extremely dangerous.  Pilots go to great lengths to avoid it, and successful ditchings get turned into Hollywood movies: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9925/has-a-commercial-airliner-ever-crash-landed-in-an-ocean

Answer (score 4):

[Some suggest](https://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-advice/health-safety/aviation-experts-guide-to-surviving-a-plane-crash-could-end-up-saving-your-life/news-story/b41e85871b748cc26a526b64b035706b) not wearing any artificial fabrics because if there is a fire or intense heat, your clothing will melt to your skin.

Given that the majority of accidents happen either at take off or landing, you’re trading one scenario for a conceivably worst one.

If you’re paranoid about an accident happening, sit at the very back, wear leather or wool, keep your shoes on, and have a portable smoke mask handy. Or take a Xanax and sleep through it all.

Comment: Or take a bus, train or ferry.

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather suggest wearing a dry scuba suit. It will be much better if you land in the ocean.

Comment: Sorry, but if your plane hits the ocean, it really won't matter what you're wearing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Within the context of the question, this is a valid answer. The question is silly, I agree.

Comment: @JanDoggen The claim that a dry suit “will be much better” is flat-out wrong. It would be exactly as bad.

Comment: You need a source of compressed air (such as a scuba tank)  for a dry suit to work properly. I doubt the airplane company will allow this on with you.